# Axios Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

first of all I had a project that i needed to send an image to AWS S3 bucket .. so I need first to send image from front end to back end so i used Axios to do that.. but now i needed to copy this code in my new application so i tested my old application first and it successfully worked .. but when i created that new application it shows me that error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXZNO.png)

sounds like the route i am giving it wrong but i checked alot of times its not wrong at all
here is my frontend code

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


async function postImage({image, description}) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", image)
  formData.append("description", description)

  const result = await axios.post('/images', formData, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  return result.data
}


function Image() {

  const [file, setFile] = useState()
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
  const [images, setImages] = useState([])

  const submit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const result = await postImage({image: file, description})
    setImages([result.image, ...images])
  }

  const fileSelected = event => {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
        setFile(file)
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        <input onChange={fileSelected} type="file" accept="image/*"></input>
        <input value={description} onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} type="text"></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Image;
```

the error that i am catching is

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

here is my backend code

```
const express = require("express");

const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
// const unlinkFile = util.promisify(fs.unlink);
const path = require("path");

const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
// const { uploadFile, getFileStream } = require("./s3");

const app = express();
  app.post('/images', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    // const file = req.file
    console.log(file)
  
  })

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log("App is listening on port " + port);
```

Comment: Did you add proxy to package.json ? 
`proxy": "http://localhost:5000`

Comment: Yes , i did that